# How to determine how far a scrollbar has moved in SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ide, swt

[Before Scroll](http://imgur.com/cHgigUu)

[After Scroll](http://imgur.com/iEBgIWy)

I am working on creating an Eclipse plugin for tracking of collections (Arrays, Array List, etc.). And I was in need of an SWT Table with expandable columns. In order to implement this, I created several SWT buttons, and generated them before I created the table, and I linked them to the columns that need to be expanded. What I'm having a problem with now is that I need a way to determine how much a user scrolled the scroll bar in order to determine what the new location of the buttons should be. For instance, if the user scrolls 10 pixels to the left, I need to move the buttons 10 pixels to the left, etc.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this within the SWT ScrollBar framework?

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve the problem by using Scrollbars "getSelection" method. Turns out, the value that this method represents is the offset from 0 of the scrollbar. In order to solve the problem, I just subtracted the getSelection value from the X position of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to solve the problem by using Scrollbars "getSelection" method. Turns out, the value that this method represents is the offset from 0 of the scrollbar. In order to solve the problem, I just subtracted the getSelection value from the X position of the buttons